# Proving set is orthonormal

Tags: orthogonality

Let $B = \{\vec{v_1} ... \vec{v_n}\}$ be basis for an n-dimensional vector space V. If $B[\vec{v_i}]_B = \vec{v_i}$ for all $1 \le i \le k$ Does that mean that $B$ is an orthogonal set? If, yes what is the proof or theorem to use for a proof? Also, does that mean that $B$ is a standard basis?

Comment: When you say $B[\vec{v_i}]_B = \vec{v_i}$  do you mean to take $B$ as a matrix with columns $v_1,\ldots,v_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem that
$$
B[\vec{v}_i]_B=\vec{v}_i
$$
indicates that the collection of vectors are orthonormal.  In fact, this statement appears to be always true.  Let's break it down:

- The term
  $$
  [\vec{v}_i]_B
  $$
  means that we're writing $\vec{v}_i$ in terms of the basis $B$ and collecting the coefficients.  Since $\vec{v}_i$ is in the basis, we see that
  $$
  0\vec{v}_1+0\vec{v}_2+\dots+0\vec{v}_{i-1}+1\vec{v}_i+0\vec{v}_{i+1}+\dots+0\vec{v}_n=\vec{v}_i.
  $$
  What $[\vec{v}_i]_B$ means is that you take the coefficients of the basis vectors of $B$ and put them into a vector.  Therefore,
  $$
  [\vec{v}_i]_B=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\0\\1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix},
  $$
  where the $1$ is in the $i^{\text{th}}$ position.  Therefore 
  $$
  [\vec{v}_i]_B=\vec{e}_i
  $$
  where $\vec{e}_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ standard basis vector (the standard basis is the one where the basis vectors have all zeros except for one $1$ - in other words, the columns of the identity matrix).
- Now, let's calculate
  $$
  B[\vec{v}_i]_B.
  $$
  One way to do matrix vector multiplication is to look at a product $B[\vec{v}_i]_B$ as a weighted sum of the columns of $B$.  In other words,
  $$
  B[\vec{v}_i]_B=B\vec{e}_i=0B_1+0B_2+\dots+0B_{i-1}+1B_i+0B_{i+1}+\dots+0B_n.
  $$
  Since the columns of $B$ are the basis vectors, it follows that
  $$
  B[\vec{v}_i]_B=0\vec{v}_1+0\vec{v}_2+\dots+0\vec{v}_{i-1}+1\vec{v}_i+0\vec{v}_{i+1}+\dots+0\vec{v}_n=\vec{v}_i.
  $$

Therefore, the given equality *always* holds - we never had to use orthogonality - so it really has very little to do with orthogonality.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful